# ie6 and ie7 remove border around image sprites

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Im using image sprites across my site.

in IE6 and IE7  a gray border appears around the images..
works fine in the other browsers +IE8

how can i remove it?
here it is the bottom one is a div:

[image]

Comment: explicitly set a border:0 on some class that's unique to the sprites?

Comment: Since you mention a gray border, could it be from png transparency?

Comment: can you give an example url or fiddle..?

Comment: Well, we don't have a lot of info but at the very top of your stylesheet you could add *{border:none;outline:none;}. Any border and outline styles that cascade below that should stay intact. That way you can figure out if it's a style you defined and need to remove. Else, if it's an browser style it should be removed anyway.

Comment: i tried {border:none;outline:none;} but didnt work. i changed my img tags into divs and now it seems to be working... -no more border

Comment: That's didn't display well, I mean add "* {border:none;outline:none;}" using the " * " selector to apply to all elements. If you got it working though, never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed image tags to divs and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,
acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,
sub,sup,tt,var,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,
thead,tr,th,td
{
    border:0;
    font-weight:inherit;
    font-style:inherit;
    font-size:100%;
    font-family:inherit
}
```

Added that code to my main css file and all the borders in IE7 disappeared.

Comment: To improve the quality of your post, please include how/why this code will solve the problem.